# Is there any python libraries to detect latitude and longitude of detected object using camera?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I wanted to detect an object using satellite camera with latitude and longitude.

Comment: You should ask about that here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly sure by what you mean by detected object using camera. I think you mean latitude and longitude of landmarks in a photo.

If that is what you mean you must check you Google Vision API : https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-landmarks

It detects famous landmarks from images and provides you with their latitude and longitude.

Comment: This is not an answer. Rules of stackoverflow says that you should provide an exact answer with example of code (if applicable) rather than just giving a link